# Understand V4L2 request buffer number

Tags: c, embedded, v4l2

I'm newbie in using V4L2 on embedded device and I have two questions related to V4L2 library usage:

First is the buffer allocation for v4l2_requestbuffers:

```
    struct v4l2_requestbuffers req;

    CLEAR(req);

    req.count = 4;
    req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
    req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
```

and later it is used by:

```
if (req.count < 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Insufficient buffer memory on %s\n",
                         dev_name);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        buffers = calloc(req.count, sizeof(*buffers));

        if (!buffers) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

for (n_buffers = 0; n_buffers < req.count; ++n_buffers) {
                struct v4l2_buffer buf;

                CLEAR(buf);

                buf.type        = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
                buf.memory      = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP;
                buf.index       = n_buffers;

                if (-1 == xioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, &buf))
                        errno_exit("VIDIOC_QUERYBUF");

                buffers[n_buffers].length = buf.length;
                buffers[n_buffers].start =
                        mmap(NULL /* start anywhere */,
                              buf.length,
                              PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE /* required */,
                              MAP_SHARED /* recommended */,
                              fd, buf.m.offset);

                if (MAP_FAILED == buffers[n_buffers].start)
                        errno_exit("mmap");
        }
```

For capturing still image, req.count is 1. For capturing video, do we need to tune the req.count number to a number that we get good fps? **That's mean we have to change the req.count from 2 (in this example) to a suitable number to get acceptable fps?**

Second question is the timeout setting, as used in the mainloop:

```
static void mainloop(void)
{
        unsigned int count;

        count = frame_count;

        while (count-- > 0) {
                for (;;) {
                        fd_set fds;
                        struct timeval tv;
                        int r;

                        FD_ZERO(&fds);
                        FD_SET(fd, &fds);

                        /* Timeout. */
                        tv.tv_sec = 2;
                        tv.tv_usec = 0;

                        r = select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

                        if (-1 == r) {
                                if (EINTR == errno)
                                        continue;
                                errno_exit("select");
                        }

                        if (0 == r) {
                                fprintf(stderr, "select timeout\n");
                                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                        }

                        if (read_frame())
                                break;
                        /* EAGAIN - continue select loop. */
                }
        }
}
```

If I set

```
/* Timeout. */
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
r = select(fd + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
```

My CPU load is 100%, I have to put it is 1 or 2 to make decrease the CPU load. If I remove timeout select() function, my CPU load is 100% again.

From my reading, the `select()` operation cost more CPU cycles but how can we remove select() and timeout setting in the mainloop()? Because when I look into other V4L2 capturing code from senior software engineer, I don't see they use timeout function as in the example above.

**So my second question is how to avoid using timeout select() but still keep low CPU load .**

Comment: Just curios if you found your solution yet.